# Titanium Studio: Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Tags: android, sdk, titanium, appcelerator, genymotion

I've tried running a proyect on Titanium Studio along with Genymotion following these guides:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Setting_up_Studio(For Titanium Studio, I tried it by pre-installing the prerequisites before Titanium Studio's installation, and by letting it automatically install them)
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+Genymotion(For Genymotion)

I installed the Android SDK's via Titanium Studio(I've tried different combinations).

I've tried running a proyect that is error free(the whole team can run it perfectly) and also I've tried running the default classic proyect on Ti Studio, and also the Alloy default template.

But whenever I run it, I get this message:
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:

Every single time. I've tried installing in different ways, different combinations and yet I've been unable to resolve this issue.

I've also researched online but I haven't found a solution yet, I've been stuck with this for 3 days. I also installed it on two different OS(windows 7 and windows 8) with two different laptops. The windows 7 had an issue with an AV that didn't add the path to the PATH environment variable. That has been solved, but I'm still with this problem.

Here's the full log(it's short) running on Trace level:

http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/55798735

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Already solved it. It was that the latest build tools apparently had no compatibility with Titanium so I had to uninstall it and install a previous build tool. This is the link where I saw it: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/178514/

Comment: you should add the comment above as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Already solved it. It was that the latest build tools apparently had no compatibility with Titanium so I had to uninstall it and install a previous build tool. This is the link where I saw it: developer.appcelerator.com/question/178514